# Ubuntu 23.10 with Thunderbolt Dock not working

Tags: thunderbolt, usb-c

I am running Ubuntu 23.10 on Asus Expertbook with a Thunderbolt USB-C Dockingstation HP G2.
I am not able to get any external monitor working.

I have no idea how to start troubleshoot. With Windows it was no problem, so the hardware supports everything and should work.